# Groovy each closure error

Tags: groovy

I know Java but completely new to Groovy. I have got some legacy code in Groovy to work on.

I have below method in Groovy:

```
def mapMyNotificationsByFruits(prefs,fruits) {
    def map = [:]
    prefs.each { MainNotification cn ->
        cn.fruits.each {
            MyNotification an ->
            def ex = map[(an.fruitId)]
            if (!ex) ex = []
            ex.add(an)
            map[(an.fruitId)] = ex
        }
    }
    log.info("map is: $map")
    return map
}
```

Above method gets called from another method as below:

```
def notificationPrefsByFruit = mapMyNotificationsByFruits(prefs, fruits)
```

When I debug on first line in `mapMyNotificationsByFruits` method, I get `prefs` as

```
MainNotification [someId=ABC123, email=abc@gmail.com, fruits=[{fruitId=XYZ123, someField=0}]]
```

On running this code, I get following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.somepackage.SomeClass$_mapMyNotificationsByFruits_closure5$_closure10.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.json.internal.LazyMap) values: [[{fruitId=XYZ123, someField=0}]]
```

What is wrong here ?

What does these line do:

```
MyNotification an ->
        def ex = map[(an.fruitId)]
        if (!ex) ex = []
        ex.add(an)
        map[(an.fruitId)] = ex
```

Is it a casting issue?

Replacing above lines with below code resolves the issue:

```
MyNotification an = it
def ex = map[(an.fruitId)]
if (!ex) ex = []
ex.add(an)
map[(an.fruitId)] = ex
```

But I am not sure if both code blocks are same and I am fixing it correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the input and expected output?

Comment: you did not give enough info but tried to address your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What does the Algorithm do?**
Given list of `MainNotification` instances it is grouping the `MyNotification` instances by `fruitId`.

*Given*:

```
[   
    [
        someId: "ABC123",
        email: "abc@gmail.com",
        fruits: [
            [fruitId : "XYZ123", someField: 0],
            [fruitId : "XYZ124", someField: 6],
        ]
    ],

    [
        someId: "XYSK",
        email: "yax@gmail.com",
        fruits: [
            [fruitId : "XYZ123", someField: 5],
            [fruitId : "XYZ124", someField: 2],
            [fruitId : "XYZ144", someField: 9],
        ]
    ]
]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[
    XYZ123 : [
            [fruitId : "XYZ123", someField: 0],
            [fruitId : "XYZ123", someField: 5]
         ],
    XYZ124 : [
            [fruitId : "XYZ124", someField: 6],
            [fruitId : "XYZ124", someField: 2]
         ],
    XYZ144 : [ 
            [fruitId : "XYZ144", someField: 9]
         ]
]
```

**Corrections:**

- fruits variable is never used on the method so please remove it.
- The method is calling each method on the prefs variable so it is
  expecting prefs to be `List<MainNotification>` instead of
  `MainNotification`.
- On the nested closure this code: cn.fruits.each is expecting each
  fruit to be instance of `MyNotification` (*this is the main fix to your
  issue btw*).

You did not post the source code for `MainNotification` and `MyNotification` so per the input data you gave on your question I modeled them like this:

```
class MainNotification{
    String someId;
    String email;
    List<MyNotification> fruits;
}

class MyNotification{
    String fruitId;
    int someField;
}
```

With the corrections and assumptions here is the working code:

```
def mapMyNotificationsByFruits(prefs,fruits) {
    def map = [:]
    prefs.each { MainNotification cn ->
        cn.fruits.each { MyNotification an ->
            def ex = map[(an.fruitId)]
            if (!ex) ex = []
            ex.add(an)
            map[(an.fruitId)] = ex
        }
    }
    println ("map is: $map")
    return map
}

MainNotification mainNotification = new MainNotification(someId: "ABC123",
        email: "abc@gmail.com",
        fruits: [new MyNotification(fruitId : "XYZ123", someField: 0)]
);

MyNotification fruits = null; //never used on the method

List<MainNotification>  prefs = [mainNotification];

def notificationPrefsByFruit = mapMyNotificationsByFruits(prefs, fruits)
```

Comment: So the replacement code at the end of my question is same as the previous code.. right ?  Since I am casting "it" as MyNotification. Is it correct ?

Comment: yeah sorry forget to mention they should result same effect.